# Rasterize (vector to raster) QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, vector, rasterization

I am trying to rasterize a vector with the QGIS 3.4 rasterize tool (not saga or grass tools). I prefer using this tool cause it is much faster. The values which i would like to burn  are found in the "cost_value" field(there is only one value in this case which is 2934). The no data value should get -9999. After i run the tool all of the values from the raster get the values from "cost_value" field. Simply said: all the pixels have the value from "cost_value" and none of them get -9999 even though i am rasterizing only one line geometry.

My settings:[image: Settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a raster of 1 pixel with and 1 pixel height.

Your raster have 1 cell, which is touched by the vector and assumes that value.

There must be enough pixels to find cells that not meet the condition of being touched by the vector.

Comment: You are right. I just realized it that i should change that to Georeferenced units. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Yes, the resolution works different if is expressed in pixels or georeferenced units. You are welcome.